# Find y value for respective x from python plot (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to find the code to find the value of 'y' to a respective 'x' value by using a plotted line graph. 
I've used matplotlib.pyplot to plot a graph. 
The 'x' value for which I want the 'y' value is not a part of the x values array. Is there a way to find the respective 'y' value for the same?

If I have to find the value of Y for X = 0.75, how do I do that?

[image]

Comment: You could try fitting a linear regression on your first two data points, then use the slope and intercept from that to get the equation for the line between them. Then plug in the x-value you want to find the corresponding y-value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We can use the `interp` function from the `numpy` library.

```py
import numpy as np
x = [0.01474926, 0.96923077, 1]
y = [1, 0.7875, 0]
np.interp(0.75, x,y)
0.8363082148652623
```

Answer (score 2):

the practical way to the **y-value** is using `np.interp` function which is also mentioned. I think the plot in the question belongs to roc_curve of LogisticRegression. So, it will be more practical to use the (precision_score, recall_score) instead of (x,y).

```
recall=np.interp (0.75, precision_score, recall_score)
```

*Note: This is the 5th question of Week-3 Assignment of "Applied Machine Learning in Python by University of Michigan" Coursera Course.*