# Find x-value where y = 0 for extended regression

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I have following dataset:

```
ID        DATE            VALUE
1         01-01-2020      98
1         02-01-2020      96
1         03-01-2020      94
2         01-01-2020      99
2         02-01-2020      90
2         05-01-2020      85
```

For each id I want to calculate the date where the value will reach 0 through linear regression. I succeeded in plotting an extended line, where I can visually through following code see the point where it reaches 0, but I don't succeed in extracting the exact date.

For now my code looks like this:

```
# convert date to ordinal 
df['DATE_ord']=df['DATE'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal)

# Create plot with current values
ax = sns.regplot(data=df,x='DATE_ord',y='VALUE')

# Set x-axis values (ordinal dates)
date_range = np.arange(730000, 760000, 1000)

# Calculate extended values
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x = df[
        "DATE_ord"].values, y = df["VALUE"].values)

line = [slope*xi + intercept for xi in date_range]

plt.plot(date_range, line, label="Fitting Line", linewidth=1)

# Convert x-axis values back to date
ax.set_xlabel('date')
new_labels = [date.fromordinal(int(item)) for item in ax.get_xticks()]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
```

I now need to find the date where the Y-value (VALUE) reaches 0. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343417/find-y-value-for-respective-x-from-python-plot-matplotlib) which more or less wants to achieve the same, but this doesn't work because the values in my slope are a different number as the predicted values for my x-axis, and I'm at a loss on how to make this work. The only thing I can think of is to calculate it with the regression expression and to fill in the numbers, but I'm not sure how to do this in a way that would work in a for-loop which I still need to create to loop through the different ID's.

Comment: For y = ax + b, do you have a and b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to do this with pandas only, without looping

Load sample data

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
'''
ID        DATE            VALUE
1         01-01-2020      98
1         02-01-2020      96
1         03-01-2020      94
2         01-01-2020      99
2         02-01-2020      90
2         05-01-2020      85
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep = '\s+')
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], dayfirst = True)
```

generate ordinals and calculate regression coefficients per group:

```
import datetime as dt
from scipy import stats
df['DATE_ord']=df['DATE'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal)
dfr = (df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda g: stats.linregress(x = g[
        "DATE_ord"].values, y = g["VALUE"].values)[0:2])
  .apply(pd.Series)
  .rename(columns = {0 : 'slope', 1:'intercept'}))
dfr
```

we get this

```
     slope      intercept
ID      
1   -2.000000   1.474948e+06
2   -3.076923   2.269096e+06
```

Now the 'zero' date is just as a solution to 0 = s * x + i which is x0 = -intercept/slope. we calculate that in ordinals and convert back to a date

```
dfr['zd_ord'] = -dfr['intercept']/dfr['slope']
dfr['zd'] = dfr['zd_ord'].astype(int).map(dt.datetime.fromordinal)
```

to get

```
     slope      intercept       zd_ord      zd
ID              
1   -2.000000   1.474948e+06    737474.00   2020-02-19
2   -3.076923   2.269096e+06    737456.35   2020-02-01
```