# Python, ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, valueerror

My question is related to the answer to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75361800/plot-a-function-that-has-two-parts-a-constant-part-and-a-variable-part-with-mat).

the difference between the code in the previous solutions and the current code on this question is as follows: on my code, I have to set the function "myfunc" returns two different results,
`if t==0: return(10)` `else: return np.sqrt(r**2 - t**2)`  instead of just one return which is:  `return np.sqrt(r**2 - t**2)` .

know if you run the file it will raise a ValueErrore,

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

can someone explain to me how to solve this, without changing the function to return one result because I need to keep it returning two results, this is just an example of the problem I have, the program I am writing is much different from this one.

thank you so much

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create the function (which you may not have access to)
def myfunc(t, r=1.0):
    if t==0:
        return (10)
    else:
        return np.sqrt(r**2 - t**2)

# generate some points at which the function has been evaluate
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)  # 100 points linearly spaced between 0 and 1
y = myfunc(t)  # the function evaluated at the points t

# assuming we just have t and y (and not myfunc), interpolate the value of
# the function at some point t1
t1 = 0.68354844
y1 = np.interp(t1, t, y)

# use piecewise to get a function which is constant below t1 and follows the
# original function above t1 (potentially evaluated at different points in t)
tnew = np.linspace(0, 1, 150)  # new (more highly sampled) points at which to evaluate the function

condlist = [tnew <= t1, tnew > t1]  # list of piecewise conditions
funclist = [y1, np.interp]  # use constant y1 for first condition and interp for second condition

# evaluate the piecewise function at tnew
yvals = np.piecewise(tnew, condlist, funclist, t, y)

# plot the original function and the new version with the constant section
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, y, label="Original function")
ax.plot(tnew, yvals, ls="--", label="Piecewise function")
ax.legend()

fig.show()
```

I am still a beginner to programming in general so please, it will be really helpful if you can write an answer that can be easy for me to understand, I really appreciate it.

Comment: `t` will be an array of values. Do you want `myfunc` to return just a single value `10` if `t` contains 0? Or do you still want `myfunc` to return an array of values, just with the index equivalent to where `t` is zero containing a value of 10?

Comment: yes, I want myfunc to return also the value 10 and plot it when t contains 0, because need the value 10  for other things in my program, so myfunc should be like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different options, so I'll try to cover each. I think you are suggesting that if you pass `t` as a single numeric value and that value is 0, then the function should just return single value of 10, but you still want it to also work when `t` is an array. In that case you could do:

```py
def myfunc(t, r=1.0):
    # check whether t is just a number (either an integer or floating point number)
    if isinstance(t, (int, float)):
        # check if t is zero
        if t == 0:
            return 10

    return np.sqrt(r**2 - t**2)
```

If, on the other hand you expect `t` to always be an array, and want `myfunc` to just return a single value of 10 if the array of `t` values contains 0, then you could do:

```py
def myfunc(t, r=1.0):
    # check whether t contains a zero
    if np.any(t == 0):
        return 10

    return np.sqrt(r**2 - t**2)
```

Finally, if you want `myfunc` to take in an array of `t` values and always output an array of values the same size as `t`, but with indexes where `t` is zero set to contain the value 10, the you could do:

```py
def myfunc(t, r=1.0):
    f = np.sqrt(r**2 - t**2)  # evaluate the function at all value

    # set values where t is zero to 10
    f[t == 0.0] = 10

    return f
```

I hope that covers all your potential options.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to replace the `t == 0` with `t.any() == 0`
Like below the code:

```
if t == 0:
if t.any() == 0:
```

As the `t` is an `numpy array` you have to check all the values inside the numpy array variable t

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by t==0? t is a numpy array (you define it as a linspace). If you mean one value from the array, then you need to iterate over it or use apply method

y = np.array([myfunc(x) for x in t])